# How to rotate some images with same class, when click on nav link - with jquery & css

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

Since the images are in the header, I can't use only CSS to rotate them by click on one of the nav links.
I tried a simple solution, but it looks something is wrong.. could you help me a bit?

There is a simple version of it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#nav ul li a").click(function () {
        $(".cog").css(
        {'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(70deg)',
         '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(70deg)',
         '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(70deg)',
         'transform' : 'rotate(70deg)'});
    });
});

});

    <header>

        <div id="header_image">

            <img id="cog" style="display: block;" class="cog" src="images/cog01.png">
            <img class="cog" src="images/cog02.png">
            <img class="cog" src="images/cog03.png">

        </div>

        <nav id="#nav">

            <ul id="fo_menu">
                <li id="fooldal" class="first"><a href="index.php">Főoldal</a></li>
                <li id="menu_separator"></li>
                <li id="bemutatkozas"><a href="index.php?oldal=1">Bemutatkozás</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple critical problems.

1. You need to `preventDefault()` on your `<a>` clicks, otherwise the user will follow the link and never see your transforms.
2. Your `id` on your `<nav>` tag is incorrect. It should not have the `#` prefix.

Also, there are a couple minor issues that should be cleaned up, but are not breaking your code:

1. You have double-wrapped your `document.ready()` handler. No need for the extra function declaration.
2. To target your clickable items you can just use `$("#nav a")` since `a` is a *descendant* of `#nav`. If you want to target only the specific *child* node structure, your selector would be `$("#nav > ul > li > a")`.

If you make those changes, the code should work just like the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#nav a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".cog").css(
      {'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(70deg)',
       '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(70deg)',
       '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(70deg)',
       'transform' : 'rotate(70deg)'});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_image">
  <img id="cog" style="display: block;" class="cog" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
  <img class="cog" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
  <img class="cog" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
</div>

<nav id="nav">
  <ul id="fo_menu">
    <li id="fooldal" class="first"><a href="index.php">Főoldal</a></li>
    <li id="menu_separator"></li>
    <li id="bemutatkozas"><a href="index.php?oldal=1">Bemutatkozás</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @webaj so, have I answered your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right :) I was a bit in hurry, and copy-pasted some element.. Actually I would roll some cogwheel, so preventDefault() is not neccessary - with it, the link not works and rotate only once, than do nothing when I click on any item in the menu :S
without preventDefault(), the weels are only roll while the page is loading, and then stop :S
(sorry for late answer, and your solution is ok, maybe my question wasn't clear enough)